android compose carousel, How to apply Hero strategy (Centered) carousels in using HorizontalUncontainedCarousel
In material3 guidelines, they mentioned Hero strategy (Centered) carousels and provided a detailed example using views (XML)
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Carousel.md
CarouselLayoutManager(HeroCarouselStrategy())

image example :
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/material-components/material-components-android/master/docs/components/assets/carousel/hero-center.png
(couldn't upload the image)
But I couldn't find anything about how to apply this strategy to Compose
Edit:
I want it using HorizontalUncontainedCarousel
because of this behaviors and animation


You can use the HorizontalUncontainedCarousel Composable to achieve a similar behavior. However, it seems that centering the item that is currently focused is not supported yet:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun CarouselDemo() {
    val carouselState = rememberCarouselState { 25 }

    Column {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(24.dp))
        HorizontalUncontainedCarousel(
            state = carouselState,
            modifier = Modifier.width(412.dp).height(221.dp),
            itemWidth = 186.dp,
            itemSpacing = 8.dp,
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp),
            flingBehavior = CarouselDefaults.singleAdvanceFlingBehavior(carouselState)
        ) { index ->
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier.height(205.dp).maskClip(MaterialTheme.shapes.extraLarge),
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.nature),
                contentDescription = "Nature",
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
            )
        }
    }
}

Output:


you need to add
flingBehavior = CarouselDefaults.singleAdvanceFlingBehavior(state)
This is not the behavior of hero strategy (centered)

You are right, it is not centering the item. I will have a look, but at the first glance centering the item seems not to be supported yet.

Yes, I have modified all carousel library to make it work. It did, but the shared element transition was glitchy on the images
